# Broadcast receiver not triggering when blocked SMS received

Tags: android, sms, broadcast, receiver, blocked

I have created one SMS broadcast receiver. When I received normal SMS receiver is triggering but, When I received blocked SMS it is not triggering (I blocked one phone number, I got some messages from blocked phone number)

```
  <receiver
        android:name=".Receiver.MySMSBroadCastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action 
        android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

I expected receiver need to be trigger ,but not triggering